# How to create a relation to multiple assets in my Plugin Model/Record?

Tags: assets, plugins, relations

I defined an `estateRecord` in my Plugin. Every estate has a set of images that i want to import from a zip file directly via `assetsService::insertFileByLocalPath()`.

In my `estateRecord` I defined a relation:

```
public function defineRelations()
{
    return array(
        'assets' => array(static::HAS_MANY, 'AssetFileRecord', 'id'),
    );
}
```

Is that correct?

Now i'm stuck to define a 'asset'-field in the estateModel to access the image-sets.

I just find a solution to define the Attribute for one assetId but have no idea how to define the Attribute for the related set of assetIds.
How can i do this?

Comment: No one with a hint for me?

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're asking is how to define the relationship using Active Record in the other direction - going from Craft's [AssetFileRecord](http://buildwithcraft.com/classreference/models/AssetFileModel) to your plugin's EstateRecord.

And the answer is that you can't without hacking the AssetFileRecord and manually adding a BELONGS_TO relation back to your Estate Record.

You're going to be much better off ditching records and active record for this all-together, I think.  Have your service layer use the [Query Builder](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.query-builder) `craft()->db->createCommand()` directly, then you can join in any data you want from any tables outside of the context of active record.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it helps me a lot! I will post my solution later.